# React - Show loader on Click that already has function assigned to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, onclick, axios

I have already a a click event within a ternary operator that does a GET request from my API. When the button is clicked, the button disappears and the data text replaces the button (button disappears). But there is a small gap of time between the get request and the text reveal. I want to put a loading message of some kind at that moment of time so the user knows something is happening. But can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export default class FoodData extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        meal: '',
        clicked: false,
        isLoaded: false,
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        clicked: true,
    });
}

fetchData() {
    axios.get('api/menu/food')
        .then(res => {
            const meal= `${res.data.starters},${ res.data.price}`;
            this.setState({
                meal: meal,
                isLoaded: true
            })
            console.log(meal)
        })
};

   combinedFunction() {
    this.fetchData();
    this.handleClick();
}

 render(){
   const {isLoaded, meal} = this.state;

 return (
    <div >
          Dish: {
            this.state.clicked ? (
            this.state.menu
           ) : (
            <button onClick={() => {  this.combinedFunction() }}>Find Dish</button>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a "isLoading" state and put the values before and after your API call like so:

```
fetchData() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    axios.get('api/menu/food')
        .then(res => {
            const meal= `${res.data.starters},${ res.data.price}`;
            this.setState({
                meal: meal,
                isLoaded: true
                isLoading: false,
            })
            console.log(meal)
        })
};
```

And use that on your render to show the "loading icon"

```
render(){
   const {isLoaded, meal, isLoading } = this.state;

 return (
    <div >
          {isLoading ? <div>loading</div> :
            Dish: {
              this.state.clicked ? (
              this.state.menu
             ) : (
              <button onClick={() => {  this.combinedFunction() }}>Find Dish</button>
            )}
          }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It kind of worked but the loading message comes before the Dish: but i want it to come inplace of the Find Dish (the text of the button). Or more specifically, when the button vanishes from its place, the loading message takes its place.

Comment: @risingmoon77 I updated the comment to your liking. kindly accept and vote if this answered your question. thanks

Comment: @I am L I Doesn't work. Dish: is now causing a parsing error.  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

Comment: @I am L never mind it, i'll just manipulate the spinning icon i have in mind to show in place using css. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working demo which shows `loading` when api call starts and disables button to prevent multiple api calls. I added a 2sec time out to show the demo. [Check the stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mnqc2y)

This is the updated code, here I used a fake api (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) to show the demo

```
   import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export default class FoodData extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        meal: '',
        clicked: false,
        isLoaded: false,
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.combinedFunction = this.combinedFunction.bind(this)
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        clicked: true,
    });
}

fetchData() {

      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .then(res => {
              this.setState({
                  meal: res.data,
                  isLoaded: false
              })
          })
};

   combinedFunction =()=> {
       this.setState({isLoaded: true})
     setTimeout(()=>{
    this.fetchData();

     },2000)
    this.handleClick();
}

 render(){
   const {isLoaded, meal} = this.state;

 return (

   <>
    <div >
          Users: 
            <button onClick={this.combinedFunction } disabled={isLoaded ? true : false}>{isLoaded ? 'Loading...':'Find User'}</button>
      </div>

      <div>
      {meal && meal.map(item =>(
        <div key={item.id}>
          <p>{item.id} - {item.name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```